# Use of "ODgzYzRlZDc0M" folder in C:\Program Files and should I delete it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox

Few days ago I saw a folder weirdly named "ODgzYzRlZDc0M" on my HP Laptop( running Windows 10 64-bit ) in C:\Program Files.

[image: Shows the location of the specified folder]

It contains a few .dll and .dat files. Since one of them has "moz" in it, am I correct in guessing the folder is created by Mozilla(I have installed Firefox Nightly)?

[image: Displays the contents of the specified folder]

Does anybody know which program created this folder?
And even though it only takes up 7.2 MB space, should I delete it?

Comment: The properties of the DLL files may tell you the creator and purpose.

Comment: If you suspect any of the files are malicious you can verify that by uploading them at virustotal.com

Comment: Thanks @AFH I didn't know this. The properties show Mozilla Corporation as the signer here and Details tab shows File Description as User-Generated Microsoft(R) C/C++ Runtime..... The copyright is of Microsoft Corporation.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The files do not contain any virus as I scanned them just, but I am confused about the purpose of this folder, outside the Mozilla Firefox folder.

Comment: Doesn't look like Mozilla Firefox at all. Just some program that uses the Mozilla "NSS" SSL library.

Comment: @grawity Any idea which programs usually do that?

Comment: In worst case, you can move the folder to a safe place and see what breaks to find out if the folder should be there or not.

Comment: @LPChip Ok, trying it